# Can I programmatically trigger "composer update" using the Composer API?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a composer script that I run that calls a static method on a class. My class does some altering to the composer.json file and then rewrites it using the `Composer\Json\JsonFile` class from the Composer API:

**composer.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "my-script": "MyScriptObject::doSomething"
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I trigger a `composer update` from inside `MyScriptObject` class using the Composer API? **I don't want to use the `pre-update-cmd`** because I cannot pass arguments to it.

In looking at the API docs I can see that there is a `Composer\Installer` class that I can use to do something like: `Composer\Installer::create(IOInterface $io, Composer $composer)->run()`, but that performs an install and loads dependencies from the lock file. I'd like to perform an update so I can regenerate the lock file.

Does anyone know where this is at in the API?

Source: https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/index.html

Comment: I would assume in PHP you could use the `shell_exec` like `shell_exec('composer update');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was right in front of me. All I had to do was `setUpdate()` before calling run:

`Composer\Installer::create($this->io, $this->composer)->setUpdate(true)->run();`

Source: https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.0.0-alpha3/src/Composer/Installer.php#L489